# Automatically reload a webpage when it expires

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML page with headers like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 07 Oct 2020 09:50:03 -0600" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

It is currently `04:45:17` on that date and I want that page to automatically reload at `09:50:03`, at which point the page will have a new expiration date in the met tag, and I want the page to reload based on the new date.

I can reload on an interval, I can use JavaScript to reload if any the files on disk change, but I can’t figure out how to reload based on the expires header. PHP or JavaScript solutions preferred.

Comment: Are you saying this meta is not causing the page to reload? May need  a little more explanation of your issue please

Comment: Do you want to refresh based on content time of   <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 07 Oct 2020 09:50:03 -0600"" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer already been given to extending existing answer with further:

```js
const expiresHeader = document.querySelector("meta[http-equiv='expires']").getAttribute('content');

let myinterval =new Date(expiresHeader).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("MyInterval:",myinterval);
 setInterval(function(){ refreshpage(); }, myinterval );
 
 
 refreshpage=()=>{
  window.location.reload(true);
 };
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 07 Oct 2020 09:50:03 -0600" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: using these http-equiv values is not reliable. Nor is it supported based on the HTML docs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-meta-http-equiv

Answer (score 2):

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
const expiresHeader = document.querySelector("meta[http-equiv='expires']").getAttribute('content');

console.log(expiresHeader);
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 07 Oct 2020 09:50:03 -0600" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Then you should use library like https://day.js.org/ or JS Date API to parse `expires` and calculate the difference between current and `expires` date. Then maybe `setTimeout` based on that difference when DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const expiresHeader = document.querySelector("meta[http-equiv='expires']").getAttribute('content');

let myinterval =new Date(expiresHeader).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("MyInterval:",myinterval);
 setInterval(function(){ refreshpage(); }, myinterval );
 
 
 refreshpage=()=>{
  window.location.reload(true);
 };
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 07 Oct 2020 09:50:03 -0600" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).